# one hosting space for two websites

Tags: domains, web-hosting, subdomain

I have a hosting + domain with a hosting company.

My question is: can I have a second website just by purchasing a new domain?

This is, I could develop a second website under mysecondwebsite.myfirstwebsite.com and my question is if I could access that website with a second domain.

The thing is that the second domain should be one that let me access secondomain.com/whatever, not just redirecting to the first domain. Additionally, going directly to mysecondwebsite.myfirstwebsite.com shouldn't be accessible.

Is that possible - one hosting space for two websites?

Answer (score 1):

If I follow your question correctly, yes, totally possible. Bluehost for example let's you host as many sites as you want under one account. The site is hosted on a folder in your main site html directory (public_html).
You can access the site via its own domain name: sitea.com & siteb.com (hosted under site a).

There's even a video explaining this: http://www.expand2web.com/blog/assign-multiple-domains-to-one-bluehost-account/

Answer (score 1):

mysecondwebsite.myfirstwebsite.com is called a subdomain, you do NOT have to purchase or register it. You are fully entitled to sell it. ( www. is a standard subdomain that just happens to be the same as the primary domain. It doesn't have to be.)

myfirstwebsite.com and mysecondwebsite.com can easily exist under the same hosting account, anyone who says otherwise is either lying or incompetent. Wether your service provider WANTS to is another question entirely, as is wether they charge or not.

How the folders are arranged is also entirely up to your hosting provider. They may use one folder for each (sub)domain, they may put subdomains inside the parent domain. Read their documentation.

How the domains interact is up to you. There is no way to stop people typing in mysecondwebsite.myfirstwebsite.com , but there are ways to make it slightly more difficult to access resources on other domains. The keyword to search for is "hotlinking".

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible.

But you have to check if your hosting company can do it. Check on their help support system.

The option mysecondwebsite.myfirstwebsite.com is called subdomain and it is the simplest way, but if you don't want that, just don't activate it on your control panel, whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible - one hosting space for two websites?

Yes, it is totally possible, as indicated in other previous answers.

How to do it?

It depends on your present hosting environment. If you are on a shared hosting environment, it might be a bit difficult to do it without the help of your web host, even though some hosts offer this feature in their control panel.

If you are on your own or you have a VPS/Dedicated server with root access, you may try the following. 
On apache, you can define two host names in your hosts.conf file and as host1 and host2 file names. You can now put the the files of both websites on two different folders in your public html folder and define both the folders as your document roots respectively in your host files. Update your DNS and point it to your ip. Apache should take care of the rest for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes..

If your hosting company provides support for multiple sites on a single server. A lot of webhostsing services do that. If this is not possible have a subdomain as you asked in the question and forward the domain using domain forwarding feature this is not a best way though.